# CAR spatial models in JAGS

Tags: spatial, jags, bugs, geostatistics

WinBUGS comes with the GeoBUGS add-on, which contains a number of predefined model structures that are suitable for modelling spatial data structures e.g. geostatical structures (spatial.exp), conditional auto-regressive, CAR, structures (car.proper, car.normal) amongst others. Unfortunately there are no comparable structures for JAGS. This discussion: http://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/280820cb on the mailing list indicates that I probably shouldn't hold my breath either.

How then can I implement a CAR model in JAGS? Does anyone have examples that they could share?

Cheers,

Mark

Comment: Why don't you download the source code of GeoBUGS to see? Hardly anyone besides GeoBUGS authors will know that....